Redesign ISO symbols to fit your company's brand language - is it ok?
I know you can buy ISO symbols but if a company, like Apple, redesign the symbols they need to have on their products (as they do) it must be ok, right?
I work for an international company and we would like to redesign some symbols but Im not 100% sure about the laws and rules. My question: Does anybody know the rules here?

This is potentially a very good question. Just two things. 1. What type of symbols do you have in mind, 2. Try to focus this on graphic design and not a legal issue.
